# How to set owl datetime picker format programmatically?

Tags: angular, typescript, datetimepicker

I have been using until recently this datetime picker...

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime

Overall it's a pretty nice project, even though it hasn't been worked on in a while. However, I'm facing a problem with it. I would like to be able to change the represented format (not the actual data, that is perfectly fine) to the user and that at any time possible.

The user is allowed to change the format of dates the way they want them to be. So formats can look like these examples:

- "20-12-2009"
- "12/20/2009"
- "2009 12 20"

I get the format preference from my backend, which in return is being used in all displaying components. Tables, or just any value that it can be applied to.

However, this application doesn't offer any way of changing the format aside the method "setLocale()". This is not much of a solution, as that literally translates the calendar to the corresponding language. So according to the documentation you can supply the component - in conjunction with moment.js - your own formats. Kinda like this...

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { OwlDateTimeModule, OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS} from 'ng-pick-datetime';
import { OwlMomentDateTimeModule } from 'ng-pick-datetime-moment';

// See the Moment.js docs for the meaning of these formats:
// https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/
export const MY_MOMENT_FORMATS = {
    parseInput: 'l LT',
    fullPickerInput: 'l LT',
    datePickerInput: 'l',
    timePickerInput: 'LT',
    monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
    dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
    monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
};

@NgModule({
    imports: [OwlDateTimeModule, OwlMomentDateTimeModule],
    providers: [
        {provide: OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS, useValue: MY_MOMENT_FORMATS},
    ],
})
export class AppExampleModule {
}
```

It works, as expected, very well. However, I would like to be able to change this programmatively later on... which sadly shows that I'm lacking understanding in coding. While I technically CAN apply...

```
@ViewChild('picker') picker: any; 
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.picker.datetimeFormat = {
// new format...
}
}
```

It's not feasible on my end, because I might or might not have a datepicker on my form, depending what fields have been clicked.

Comment: Good question. I have a similar question: How to have different formatting for different pages? I want to show seconds on one page, but not on the other. It's good that there is a way to set the _default_ formatting for the control, but there needs to be a way to set it at the control level instance level. I think there should be HTML tags to control formatting. I would use that to set it statically and differently on my two pages  (format="h:m:s"). You would use it to change the settings dynamically ([format]="formatVariable".

Comment: The project appears to be abandoned and the owner hasn't been active on github for close to 10 months now. And since the settings of the date picker are always picked on runtime, there is no decent way to change the format for specific instances in reactive forms. And using the ViewChildren feels so exceptionally hackish for this particular issue