# How to setup multiple formats in same app for ng-pick-datetime

Tags: angular, typescript, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I know how to setup *default* formatting for ng-pick-datetime via OWL_DATE_TIME_FORMATS (https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/#locale-formats), but what I want is to setup formatting differently on different pages in my app. On one page I want seconds and on the other I don't. Using momentjs that would be LT for one and LTS for the other.

But, I don't see how to setup different formats for different instances of the control in my app. Seems that you can setup the default and that's it.

Seems that a nice way to handle it would be an HTML tag. Consider this example with my imagined owlFormat tag:

```
        <owl-date-time owlFormat="LTS"></owl-date-time>
```

Does such a tag or some other mechanism exist to set the format for a control?

Note that if such a tag exists, then it could used to what the OP asks for in:
[How to set owl datetime picker format programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56129112/how-to-set-owl-datetime-picker-format-programmatically). They could assign like:

```
   [owlFormat]="formatVariable"
```

Reference:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime